# Router Backbone JS with Ecmascript 6

Tags: backbone.js, ecmascript-6, router

I do not understand how to use the Router of BACKBONE.JS with ecmascript 6..

```
export default class RouterApp extends Backbone.Router.extend{
constructor(){
    super();
    this.routes = {
        '' : 'home'
    };

}
function home(){
    alert('hello');
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow 199204. This is not a [very good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Try to specify more clearly what is going wrong, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: I am developing an application with react js and BACKBONE.JS using ecmascript 6, but i do not understand how working backbone js with ecmascript 6.

Comment: In general, it seems backbonejs doesn't work very well with ES6 classes (see https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/3560).  Initial issue I see with your class though is that your "function home()" method isn't how you format ES6 class methods, it should just be home().  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes for more info about how to write ES6 classes